# BizTalk deployment framework installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, biztalk, btdf

I have installed BizTalk Deployment Framework5.7 (ThomasAbhram).

When I open a project in VS 2013 and then try to add new project from solution explorer of opened project i can see "deployment Framework for BizTalk project".
But when Go to Tools I am not able to see the option "Deployment framework for BizTalk."

Please anybody help on this.How can i get that otion under Tool.

I follow the blog [Visual Studio 2013 and BTDF 5.6](http://rakeshs1979.blogspot.com/2015/12/visual-studio-2013-and-btdf-56.htm). In step 7 I am not able to see this "Deployment framework for BizTalk" in VS 2013.

While installation I used COMPLETE option (In step 2 ) .

Comment: I followbelow blog http://rakeshs1979.blogspot.com/2015/12/visual-studio-2013-and-btdf-56.html. In step 7 i am not able to see this "Deployment framework for biztalk" in TOOLS in VS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, even though I'd installed the BTDF MSI - I'd failed to install the Visual Studio extension for BTDF. This can be done by:

- selecting Tool\Extensions and Updates
- with the "Online" tab" selected, searching "BTDF"

[image: search for btdf]

Comment: Issue not resolved... i cannt see the option in TOOLS. Please help

Comment: You don’t have extensions and updates option on the tools menu? Are you using professional edition of visual studio?